# When someone touches a red circle on my app nothing happens

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I am making an app that displays circles randomly on the screen. The circles are either red or green. The purpose of the app is so that when someone touches a green circle something good happens, like they get points added to their score. When a red circle is clicked something bad happens like a new activity is started and the page says you failed or something. Here is my code for this app. In this code i receive no errors, nothing in logcat, everything works just fine. The circles display randomly on the screen as well as the score which is by default 0. The problem i am having with this app is that when a red or a green circle is clicked nothing happens.

```
public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }
    RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, 200, 0);

    private static final int w = 100;
    public static int lastColor = Color.BLACK;
    private final Random random = new Random();
    private final Paint paint = new Paint();
    private final int radius = 230;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    public static int redColor = Color.RED;
    public static int greenColor = Color.GREEN;
    int randomWidth = 0;
    int randomHeight = 0;
    public static int addPoints = 0;


    private final Runnable updateCircle = new Runnable() {
        @Override 
        public void run() {
            lastColor = random.nextInt(2) == 1 ? redColor : greenColor;
            paint.setColor(lastColor);
            invalidate();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

        }
    };

    @Override 
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        handler.post(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // your other stuff here
        if(random == null){
            randomWidth =(int) (random.nextInt(Math.abs(getWidth()-radius/2)) + radius/2f);
            randomHeight = (random.nextInt((int)Math.abs((getHeight()-radius/2 + radius/2f))));
        }else {
            randomWidth =(int) (random.nextInt(Math.abs(getWidth()-radius/2)) + radius/2f);
            randomHeight = (random.nextInt((int)Math.abs((getHeight()-radius/2 + radius/2f))));
        }

        canvas.drawCircle(randomWidth, randomHeight, radius, paint);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(150);
        canvas.drawText("Score: " + addPoints, 120, 300, paint);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   int x = (int) event.getX();
   int y = (int) event.getY();
   if(isInsideCircle(x, y) ==  true){
      //Do your things here
       if(redColor == lastColor){
          Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), YouFailed.class);
          v.getContext().startActivity(i);
       } else {
           addPoints++;
       }
   }else {

   }
   return true;
}

public boolean isInsideCircle(int x, int y){
  if ((((x - randomWidth)*(x - randomWidth)) + ((y - randomHeight)*(y - randomHeight))) < ((radius)*(radius))){
    return true;
  }
  return false; 
}


}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your touch (x,y) are inside circle? And why are you not checking that which `action` it is, i.e. either `DOWN`, `MOVE` or `UP`. @Paul

Comment: put the debug point here "int x = (int) event.getX();" and ensure it gets  executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your view might not be implementing the [`View.OnTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) interface, hence it not calling the `onTouch()` method.
2. Your view is not being set a View.OnTouchListener via the view's `View.setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener)` method.

[Android Developer Reference - View.OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

Either way it feels wrong to make a view implement this interface to listen to itself. Instead you may want to take a look at the `View.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method; perhaps it serves your purpose (or it *should* in this case). Listener interfaces are supposed to be implemented by external components. Say, for example, if you wanted to make your TextView listen every time a Button or ImageView is touched, you could extend TextView/Button and make them implement the Listener interface then pass it to you view as a parameter of its `setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener)`.

However, all views have a method called `onTouchEvent()`. This [`View.onTouchEvent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) method should be used if you want to listen to events *within* the view itself, as it is by default called whenever the view is, well *touched*. Should you need a reference to the view itself with this approach, you call `this` since the view itself would be your current scope.

[Android Developer Reference - View.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

If you do it like this, all you would need to do in order to make your code work is change your `onTouch()` method to an override of `onTouchEvent()` like this: (Also added verification of touch action as suggested by Pooja and Tom so you don't take into account `MOVE` or `UP` events. Change `DOWN` for `UP` depending on when you want to trigger the event)

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        if(isInsideCircle(x, y) ==  true) {
            //Do your things here
            if(redColor == lastColor){
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), YouFailed.class);
                this.getContext().startActivity(i);
            } else {
                addPoints++;
            }
        } else {
             //Handle case not inside the circle
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought that extending the view class took its interfaces with it? I tried to implement it, but eclipse wouldn't let me

Answer (score 0):

The `onTouch` method is meant to be used with `OnTouchListener` and would normally be defined outside your custom view class. For example:

```
    this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // touch handling code
            return true;
        }
    });
```

In the case where you are looking for touch events inside your custom view, you should implement the `onTouchEvent` method. You may also want to check for either `ACTION_UP` or `ACTION_DOWN` or you will be processing multiple touch events.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    boolean result = false;

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        if(isInsideCircle(x, y) ==  true) {
            //Do your things here
            if(redColor == lastColor){
               Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), YouFailed.class);
               v.getContext().startActivity(i);
            } else {
               addPoints++;
            }
            result = true;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

See the following for more details:
[Input Events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)